# How can I hook a user back into my activity after I have sent them off?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-2.2-froyo

My app will detect if the user has a TTS engine installed, if not I'll disable all functionality and give them a button which they can click to "install a TTS" (Its better to give them the choice rather than go off automatically?)

The button does this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.languageselection);

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

}

protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);


            speakEnglishButton.setEnabled(true);
            speakFrenchButton.setEnabled(true);
            speakSpanishButton.setEnabled(true);
            speakGermanButton.setEnabled(true);
            speakItalianButton.setEnabled(true);

        } else {
            speakEnglishButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakFrenchButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakSpanishButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakGermanButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakItalianButton.setEnabled(false);

            Toast.makeText(this, "No TTS installed....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            setContentView(R.layout.nottsengine);


        }
    }
}
```

**Question** : After the call to `startActivity(installIntent);` how can I hook them back into my activity? If they have installed the TTS engine OK, I want to then enable the functionality. If they did go off into that activity but didn't install the TTS I need to keep functionality disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a [BroadcastReciver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to be notified when TTS pack is installed. Add this to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".InstallNotifier">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.speech.tts.engine.TTS_DATA_INSTALLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```